# 3 column display:flex layout with overflow:ellipsis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to have a layout where the middle column has a flexible width; it should take all space that is not taken by first and last column.

First column is always 50px, last column width is determined by it's contents. As said, middle column should take remainder.

Tried some things with display:flex but can't work it out.

You can see what I tried here;

https://jsfiddle.net/qwxxdkpd/1/

However, middle column is overflowing and pushing third column out of sight.

Correct should be that the middle column is cut off, because I use the following;

```
#container .list .address {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -webkit-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix it;

Should look as this:

```
Icon|11111111111111111111111111111...|1.2 (end of line)
```

Comment: That `HTML` structure ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @NenadVracar lol is it really that bad? :-)

Comment: Why is `ul li` with one `li` there? :)

Comment: @NenadVracar I did remove multiple li's to make the example "simpler" :-)

Comment: Maybe something like this https://jsfiddle.net/qwxxdkpd/2/?

Comment: @NenadVracar that's exactly it, thanks! can you submit as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important part is to use `flex: 1` and `overflow: hidden` on `.details` and `white-space: nowrap`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` on `.address`

```css
#container .list ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#container .list li {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1d1b8;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#container .list li > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#container .list .type {
  padding-right: 15px;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background: green;
}

#container .list .type i {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#container .list .details {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Courier New";
}
.address {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#container .list .value {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 55px;
}

#container .list .details .date {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="list">
     <ul>
       <li>
        <div class='type'><i class='fa fa-arrow-circle-right'></i></div>
        <div class='details'>
          <div class='date'>date</div>
          <div class='address'>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</div>
         </div>
         <div class='value'>1.2</div>         
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation, now I understand it a little better :-)

Comment: just one more question if you don't mind, any idea why the - #container .list li > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
} - rule is not applied ?

Comment: seems each div in the row has the same height, instead of the theight of it's contents.

Comment: In flexbox you use `align-items: center` on flex container  instead https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/960/

Comment: thanks again seems this is the holy grail of HTML grid design and I need to read more about it :D

Comment: You're welcome, you can start here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes.